# How do I retrieve text from inside the html using wallaby/elixir?

Tags: elixir, wallaby

I need to use the digits displayed in the HTML to make test with elixir/ wallaby.

ex:

```
class="app-add-installemnts-link">14903 1/3</a></td>
```

How can I retrieve the number: **14903 1/3**

Is there a function or a way to do this?

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/wallaby/readme.html#queries-and-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wallaby.Browser function like this:

```
Wallaby.Browser.text(session, css(".app-add-installemnts-link"))
```

More details here: https://hexdocs.pm/wallaby/Wallaby.Browser.html#text/2

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one matching element:

```
find(css(".app-add-installemnts-link")
|> Element.text()
```

[Reference](https://hexdocs.pm/wallaby/Wallaby.Query.html#content)